# Is it possible to optimize a range query so an explain statement would state "using index" instead of "using index condition"?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, index

I have a very large table where specific queries made by my application are timing out.  The table looks something like this:

```
LargeTable
------------
Id [BIGINT(20)]
UtcTimestamp [BIGINT(20)]
Pivot [BIGINT(20)]
Details [Text]
```

I have an index over `1) Pivot 2) UtcTimestamp`.

Now, the query I'm running looks something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Pivot, UtcTimestamp, Details FROM
LargeTable WHERE 
UtcTimestamp>=1380067200 AND UtcTimestamp<=1380153599 AND Pivot=2;
```

Since there is an index over the pivot and timestamp, this query should be blazing fast, but it doesn't appear to be.  I ran an explain on this query expecting "using index", but instead I get "using index condition". Here is the explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys          | key                   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LargeTable  | range | pivot_and_timestamp_id | pivot_and_timestamp_id| 18      | NULL |  963 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
```

It's definitely selecting the right index, but *why is this query not as fast as it should be?*

The MySQL server version is 5.6.14.

Comment: Whats the MySQL server version and how does the table look like? and show us all columns in the select please and not [more selects here] ....

Comment: And the used storage engine?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Innodb.  Sorry I didn't explicitly state that, I thought it was implied from the tags

Comment: You only get "Using index" when you write querys that select data from the index only Details isn't indexed so innodb needs to look that up in the table data (extra random I/O needed) if the innodb buffer doens't have this data..

Comment: But Using index condition is pretty good because it finds the rangs off UtcTimestamp>=1380067200 AND UtcTimestamp<=1380153599 and checks the Pivot value here

Comment: And how does an  EXPLAIN SELECT Id, Pivot, UtcTimestamp, Details FROM
LargeTable  IGNORE INDEX(Pivot) WHERE 
UtcTimestamp>=1380067200 AND UtcTimestamp<=1380153599 AND Pivot=2;    look like?

Comment: That clears up some points of confusion, thank you.  If I ignore the index, I get a massive row count with "using where", which is expected.  Since the Details column is a large text column (with ~1500 characters), I imagine that the lookup to pull that off disk might have become my bottleneck.

Comment: TEXT columns could even trigger more random I/O seeks because innodb could separate these between pages  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html read "How Pages Relate to Table Rows"   best option i think is to vertical partition the table and store TEXT columns in an separate table and i need to benchmark this sometime to make sure if it matters alot with and without compression see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-compression.html

Comment: I'm curious, wouldn't storing the TEXT columns in a separate table also have the end result of the data stored between pages?  What is the computational benefit in that scenario?  Thanks for your insight, by the way

Comment: Hard to say what the computational benefit will be the MySQL source code is pretty complex to analyse on some parts.. But the source code is becomming better since version 5.7 because Oracle is working on this now.. but is it known innodb will perform best when you always try to fit the pages with fixed length data because an Page could have Free space (fragmentation) also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-page-structure.html.. still it should need an benchmark to make sure..